# Can I get the ID of my new record with the PostPersist and persist/duplicate it in a ID2 field

Tags: symfony, doctrine

For some reason I would like my ID from my entity Category to be duplicate in some other field (ID2)

To do this I use PostPersist. I tried this (see code below)

but the field ID2 has still NULL as a value.

```
/**
* Category
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
*/
class Category
{ 
    /**
    * @var integer
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @var integer
    * @ORM\Column(name="idpo", nullable=true, type="integer")
    */
    private $id2;

    /**
    * @ORM\PostPersist()
    */
    public function duplicateId()
    {
       $id         = $this->getId();
       $this->id2  = $id;       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a doctrine listener in order to get access to the EntityManager and persist the entity again:

**src/Your/OwnBundle/Resources/config/services.yml**

```
services:
    yob.listener.category:
        class: Your\OwnBundle\Listener\CategoryListener
        tags :
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
```

**src/Your/OwnBundle/Listener/CategoryListener.php**

```
<?php

namespace Your\OwnBundle\Listener;

use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Your\OwnBundle\Entity\Category;

class CategoryListener implements EventSubscriber
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            'postPersist'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $event
     */
    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $event)
    {
        $entity = $event->getEntity();
        $em     = $event->getEntityManager();

        if ($entity instanceof Category) {

            $entity->duplicateId();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();
        }
    }
}
```

However, it's pretty weird to have the same field duplicated...

Btw, you can use Entity Listeners too, I haven't yet but check it out http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners

Comment: I do not always duplicate the id. Actually my Entity is a TAG object linked to ARTICLE. But some TAG are children to other TAG. and I wanted to have for parent TAG its own id in the filed that link the Tag children with the tag parent. So that I can easily retrieve all tag family linked to an Article.